# How to parse a fixed string with FParsec

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I'm trying to parse fixed strings with FParsec. For example [parsing `null` from the documentation](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#parsing-json):

```ml
open FParsec

type Json = JNull
let jnull : Parser<_>  = stringReturn "null" JNull
```

then running `jnull` on `"null"` gives the expected result

```ml
> run jnull "null";;
val it : ParserResult<Json,unit> = Success: JNull
```

But if I run it on `"nulls"` it also succeeds

```ml
> run jnull "nulls";;
val it : ParserResult<Json,unit> = Success: JNull
```

Then I tried to add the requirement that `null` should be followed by a space:

```
let jnull : Parser<_>  = stringReturn "null" JNull >>. spaces
```

However, this gives me the same result as before.

I also tried to use `manyMinMaxSatisfyL`:

```
let jnull: Parser<_> =
        manyMinMaxSatisfyL 4 4 isLower "should be null"
        >>. pstring "null"
        >>. spaces
```

This one fails on `"nulls"` as it should, but is also fails on `"null"`:

```
> run jnull "nulls";;
val it : ParserResult<unit,unit> =
  Failure:
Error in Ln: 1 Col: 5
nulls
    ^
Expecting: 'null'

> run jnull "null";; 
val it : ParserResult<unit,unit> =
  Failure:
Error in Ln: 1 Col: 5
null
    ^
Note: The error occurred at the end of the input stream.
Expecting: 'null'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or did I completely misunderstand something about parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, parsers always consume some input, produce a result and leave the rest of the input for later processing. This makes it possible to compose them, but it means that it's tricky to write a parser that consumes the whole input.

One way to do what you want is to use `notFollowedBy anyChar` like this:

```
let jnull : Parser<_,unit> = 
  (stringReturn "null" JNull) >>. notFollowedBy anyChar 

run jnull "null"  // Success
run jnull "nulls" // Error
```

The `notFollowedBy` parser succeeds if the rest of the input cannot be parsed using the parser given as argument. Here, this means that `notFollowedBy anyChar` succeeds only if the rest cannot be parsed using `anyChar`, i.e. it is empty.

Comment: A slightly simpler way to do this is to use `eof` instead, which only succeeds at the end of the input.